# Is there a way to set bash flags for a single command?

Tags: bash, shell

Any better way to do this?

```bash
set -x; ls; set +x
# rest of the script
```

Comment: It's not a lot shorter, but you could `(set -x; ls )`

Answer (score 4):

For the case that you show, you may use

```bash
( set -x; ls )
```

The `set` operation modifies the local environment in the subshell but not the environment outside of it.

Note that the subshell can't change anything in the parent environment, such as the values of variables, etc.

Also note that your code unsets the `xtrace` shell option at the end unconditionally (i.e, it would turn it off even if your script was invoked with `bash -x`), whereas using a subshell, as shown above, will retain the original setting, regardless of whether `set -x` was active or not from the start.

Related:

- [localize shopt options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567565)

Answer (score 2):

Since version 4.4, options from the first set of options (those set with `set`/`set -o`/`shopt -o` as opposed to the one set with `shopt` without `-o`) can be made local to a function with `local -` à la ash (`$-` is the special parameter that records the current set of enabled options), so you could define a function like:

```
xtrace() {
  local -
  set -o xtrace
  "$@"
}
```

And call:

```
xtrace ls
```

Note that since the command is called in the context of that `xtrace` function, `xtrace return` or `xtrace typeset var` or `xtrace shift` won't work as expected.

You could also take the opportunity to define `PS4` locally in the function:

```
xtrace() {
  local - PS4='xtrace: running '
  set -o xtrace
  "$@"
}
```

```
bash-5.2$ xtrace echo "hello world"
xtrace: running echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

The equivalent syntax for `zsh` would be:

```
xtrace() {
  set -o localoptions -o xtrace
  local PS4='...'
  "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it will depend on what you mean by "*better*". For example, you could use a subshell,

```
( set -x; ls )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke a new shell with a command instead of `( ... )` and add `-x` flag.

```bash
bash -x -c 'ls'
```

This might be useful if you want to use a different shell from your current environment.